# Advice method in a class that implements Runnable

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, aspectj, runnable

I have a overriden run() method in a class, that implements `java.lang.Runnable` and I am passing instances of that class to `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`.
The run method could throw runtime exception and I want to use AspectJ in order to create @AfterThrowing advice around that method and to add some behavior if an exception is thrown.

I know little about proxying, and due to the fact, that ThreadPoolExecutor is responsible for calling the run() method, i am not able to advice it directly by using

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.mypackage.MyClass.run())")
```

Is there any other way to implement some behavior if that method throws an exception, but after the method execution has finished ?

I was thinking of advising some method in the ThreadPoolExecutor, which is responsible for calling the run() method, but not sure how is the lifecycle there..

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that there are two types of AOP you can use in Spring? The default one is Spring AOP which only supports method execution interception in Spring beans/components. Then there is AspectJ which is completely independent of Spring but can also be used from within Spring. You just need to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP and your after-throwing advice should work. But I guess if you make your runnable class a Spring component, it should also work.

Comment: I am using org.aspectj - aspectjweaver and my runnable class is not a component.. but i am not able to make @AfterThrowing to work.. i thought that it was something related to the fact that i have overriden method or something..

Comment: That _aspectjweaver_ is one of your dependencies does not mean you are using AspectJ, it is also needed in order to parse AspectJ syntax for Spring AOP which uses a subset of the AspectJ language syntax for its purposes. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then edit your question in order to produce one or push a sample project to GitHub. I need Maven POM (if applicable), Spring configuration, full application class and full aspect code at least.